# In microprocessor 8085, how can I clear/reset all flags(s,z,ac,p,cy) without affecting contents of accumulator?

Tags: 8085

I only know the code in which accumulator contents are affected. It is not a duplicate as I have asked for a solution which doesn't affect accumulator.

Comment: no in that case, accumulator contents are being affected..

Comment: I think not in the answer? I can be mistaken, but this thing is over 40(!) years old, and I don't feel like breathing the dust off it's datasheet...

Comment: This is **not a duplicate** - as the asker correctly points out,  the other question does not seek to preserve the accumulator contents, and the offered answer does not do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the all the flags by executing instructions which affect them appropriately. Here's a method that only uses one register and no stack (this example uses B):-

```
 MVI B,0  ; B = 0
 INR B    ; B = 1 (resets Sign, Zero, Parity and Auxiliary Carry flags) 
 STC      ; set Carry flag
 CMC      ; complement Carry flag
```

The INR (Increment Register) instruction sets S, Z, P and AC flags according to the result of the increment. 1 is positive and not zero, so the S and Z flags are reset. It has an odd number of '1' bits so P is reset, and there is no carry from bit 3 so AC is reset.

INR does not affect the Carry flag, so we must reset it separately. Unfortunately the 8085 does not have a 'reset carry' instruction, but it does have 'set carry' and 'complement carry'.

By loading different numbers into the register and/or varying the other instructions you could set or reset flags at will. This is useful for returning status information that can be quickly responded to using conditional jump instructions. The flag values can represent whatever you want (eg. P flag set does not have to mean 'even parity').

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `POP PSW` instruction.

1. Move the current contents of the accumulator into the corresponding part of a register pair, for example A -> C
2. Zero the other half of that register pair
3. Push that register pair onto the stack
4. Pop the accumulator and PSW off the stack.

Looking up the actual 8085 mnemonics and verifying that it is the lower (vs upper) half of the register pair which corresponds to the accumulator in a `POP PSW` is left as an exercise to the reader.

If this seems roundabout, while it is possible there is a better way, keep in mind that there isn't ordinarily a *reason* to do what you are trying to do, apart from a subroutine call/return or more drastic context switch like a hardware or software interrupt (or obscure things like writing a debugger), and so the stack is the most common source of re-initialization of the flags.